# Intercepting and Re-Directing Windows File Operations in a C Program

Tags: windows, folder-redirection, hook

My intention is to write a program (I have Pelles C) whose function is to intercept Windows reads/writes to certain directories, and re-direct them to other, user-specified ones. For example, a certain software is hard-coded to write to C:\Windows\Temp, ignoring the system TEMP an TMP environment variables. When any program requests a file operation, mine would intercept the request, obtain the target directory, compare it to entries from a user-created list, then see that all reads/writes get redirected to the desired location (say, D:\Temp).
My biggest obstacle is that I don't know programming specific to Windows (although I know ANSI C). And my Google research hasn't been all that fruitful, either. I'm hoping someone can point me to some resources which might be helpful in solving this problem.
Note: The target systems are all 64-bits running either  Windows 7, 8.1, and 10.

Comment: You're going to set off every alarm about file interception that Windows has by doing it this way.  Windows already has a built-in way to set this up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please clarify how to access this built-in functionality?

Comment: It's called an [NTFS File Junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point).

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using NTFS file junctions (For example, I've renamed the C:\Windows\Temp directory to Temp.orig then did: mklink /J C:\Windows\Temp D:\Temp). I just wasn't sure if that was a "proper" way of doing it. I'll stick with the juctions for now.

Comment: Yes, that is the proper way to do it. Or at least it is the way that was created to handle this situation.

Comment: Even though I had asked about how to get this done by writing a program, the answers provided are functionally equivalent for my purposes (not to mention much easier). I'll consider this as solved. Thanks to CDove & EBGreen.